# Como usar una interfaz o type para una respuesta de axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, api, axios

La respuesta de una llamada a una API encargada de devolver información sobre una dirección IP está estructurada de este modo:

```
interface IpDetails {
  ip: string;
  location: Location;
  as: As;
  isp: string;
}

interface As {
  asn: number;
  name: string;
  route: string;
  domain: string;
  type: string;
}

interface Location {
  country: string;
  region: string;
  city: string;
  lat: number;
  lng: number;
  postalCode: string;
  timezone: string;
  geonameId: number;
}
```

Y el custom hook que hago para hacer la llamada de dicha API es esta:

```
export const UseIp = <T,>(ip: string) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState<T | null>(null);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState<string | null>(null);

useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
        setLoading(true);
        try {
            const response = await axios.get(ip);
            setData(response.data);
        } catch (error:any) {
            setError(error.message);
        }
        setLoading(false);
    };
    fetchData();
}, [ip])

return { data, loading, error };
}
```

Quiero usar esa data para renderizar un mapa con leaftlet, de esta forma:

```
const { data, error, loading } = UseIp(`${BASE_URL}&ipAddress=${ip}`);

if (loading) return <div>Loading...</div>;

if (error) return <div>There was an error: {error}</div>;

                <MapContainer
                    center={[data.location.lat, data.location.lng]}
                    zoom={13}
                    scrollWheelZoom={false}
                >
                </MapContainer>
```

Si funciona pero al acceder a la informacion de la data me sale el siguiente error de typescript:

```
Property location does not exist on type {}
```

Soy nuevo en typescript y creo que se debe a que no está correctamente tipado, como tengo que hacer para que ese error desaparezca ? seria implementando la interfaz del principio ? y si es asi, como se haria?

Comment: Probaste inicializando tu data del tipo `IpDetails | null`?

Comment: El hook useIp recibe un generic type T, pero parece que no lo estás pasando, supongo que ese generic type es la interface ipDetails,  sería algo como useIp<ipDetails>(…etc)

Comment: Gracias, eso lo solucionó. No me había dado cuenta

Comment: Si, de acuerdo, puedes publicarla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se puede ver en la declaración del hook `UseIp` que necesita un Generic type `T`:

```
export const UseIp = <T,>(ip: string) => { ... }
```

Hay que enviar ese generic type, que es la interface `ipDetails` al invocar a `UseIp`:

```
const { data, error, loading } = UseIp<ipDetails>(`${BASE_URL}&ipAddress=${ip}`);
```